# Rails 4 - production images and fonts not pointing to fingerprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I imported a custom theme into my Rails app for the home page. I've copied the entire folder into `app/assets/customlibrary` so that I don't have to split up the theme's files.

When I run my app in the production environment, Rails isn't able to find the fingerprinted assets in `app/assets/customlibrary/*` when they are referenced in 
`app/assets/customlibrary/css/style.css`.

For example in `style.css`, `background: url("../images/hero-image.jpg")` results in `GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/hero-image.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

I can't figure out how to fix this. Any advice?

### folder structure

`app/assets/customlibary/css/*`
`app/assets/customlibary/css/style.css`
`app/assets/customlibary/js/*`
`app/assets/customlibary/fonts/*.(svg|eot|woff|tff|)`
`app/assets/customlibary/images/*`
`app/assets/customlibary/images/hero-image.jpg`

`app/assets/stylesheets/themes/theme.css'`
`app/assets/stylesheets/style1.css'`
`app/assets/stylesheets/style2.css'`

### application.rb

```
config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
config.filter_parameters += [:password]
config.encoding = "utf-8"

# setup bower components folder for lookup
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components', 'bootstrap-sass-official', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'customlibrary')

# customlibrary assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( css/* fonts/* images/* js/* )
# normal stuff
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:png|jpg)$/
config.assets.precompile += %w( base.css )
config.assets.precompile += ['themes/theme.css']
config.assets.precompile += ['style1.css', style2.css', ... ]
```

### production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true

config.eager_load = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_assets = true

config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.digest = true

config.assets.version = '1.0'

config.log_level = :debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a path in `config.assets.paths` does not mean it makes the asset available from the web root of your application. (Which is `my_app/public`)

It adds a directory to the lookup path used by Sprockets and the asset helpers. When linking to assets from your stylesheets you can change the extension to `.css.erb` and use interpolation:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= image_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

If you are using SASS, [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) maps the Rails asset helpers to SASS functions so you can just use:

```
.class { background-image: image-url("image.png") }
```

This does not require you to rename the file.

Comment: Although in the long run you should probably abandon the concept of themes. It makes your code less organized and violates the principle of least suprise.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without editing adding `image_path` or `image-url` (I am using SASS for my custom CSS)? I use `image-url` in my own SASS code. I'm using themes because I didn't want to write my own CSS for the majority of the UX so I bought a theme online).

Comment: Just adapt the CSS of the theme to the rails asset pipeline. Its probably less work then going the other way around.

Comment: And yes using the asset helpers is the only way if you want fingerprinting. Otherwise you just have a bunch of literal links in your stylesheet.